# how run input() in my own code editor in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an code editor but when use **input()** code in inside my own code editor and try to run my terminal shows  this error

error:-

```
Enter any number

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\coding notes\pytho project\editor\new.py", line 1, in <module>

    T = int(input("Enter any number\n"))

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What modification I have to do So that my run function works correctly

this is my run function:-

```
def Run(event=None):
    global file
    if file == "":
        pass
    else:
        command = f'python "{file}"'
        run_file = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        Output, error = run_file.communicate()
        output.insert(END,f"{file}>>\n")
        output.insert(END,Output)
        output.insert(END,error)
```

full code(not full code short version of real code):-

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
def Open(event=None):
    global file
    file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".py",filetypes=[("Python Files","*.py")])
    if file == "":
        file = None
    else:
        editor.delete(1.0,END)
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            editor.insert(1.0,f.read())
def Run(event=None):
    global file
    if file == "":
        pass
    else:
        command = f'python "{file}"'
        run_file = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        Output, error = run_file.communicate()
        output.insert(END,f"{file}>>\n")
        output.insert(END,Output)
        output.insert(END,error)
root = Tk()
file = ""

editor = Text()
editor.pack()
output = Text(height=15)
output.pack()

root.bind("<Control-o>",Open)
root.bind("<Shift-Return>",Run)



root.mainloop()
```

You can see the error in this image, this is the code editor that  I have created:-
[image]

Comment: Which python version are you using? If Python 2, then [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449433/14465779)

Comment: When I have seen this error, it's because the code editor I'm using requires the input to be in `stdin` before running the code, instead of inputting during runtime. It expects something to be there, but there isn't (**E**nd **O**f **F**ile when reading a line)

Comment: `input()` requires a *real* console/terminal.

Comment: So how can I create a console/terminal please